# How can I stop and close random opening of a URL by single and double click of a button?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Swing application, where I put a five URLs in a String array, I create a START and Stop button.

When I click on the start button all the URL are opened in a browser. I  want
to do that, when I will  signal click on  stop  button  the process of opening
the browser will stop.

Suppose in between five URL  three URL are opening and I single click on stop button remaining two URL will not be opened in browser.

And when I will  double click on stop button all the browser will be closed, such that if I double click on stop button all the three URL will be closed.

How can I do that?

I have done the  browser opening code.

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser; 

 private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
 {                                      

 String line[]={"https://google.com","https://www.facebook.com":};

      for( int i=0;i<=line.length;i++)
      {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);
        jTabbedPane1.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        browser.loadURL(line[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post your stop button code. Btw. what is your question?

Comment: Did you try using [`Browser.dispose()`](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/Browser.html#dispose--)?

Comment: yes, i have done that , but its not working, because browser are opening from a start button, private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){..... }, and as void does not return any value, thats why i  put  that  above code in a function  , and i call it inside the start button.

Comment: yes, i have done that , but its not working, because browser are opening from a start button, private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){..... }, and as void does not return any value, thats why i  put  that  above code in a function  , and i call it inside the start button. also i create get and set method  for passing the value of single click and double click of stop  button click event, but also its not working